# Running TF2 on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, screen, steam

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with an old Intel Pentium CPU (mobile Intel GL40) and an Intel GMA 4500M onboard graphics card.

I downloaded the Linux-version of Steam and TF2 via Steam without using any kind of emulator or other programs. Since I got an error message starting TF2. I updated my graphics card driver.

Now I can start TF2 but I get strange graphics bug and cant play (for example the Valve intro is inversed combined with a strange green/black/blue pixel pattern - it is not playable although I have the feeling that I am in the main menu and hear the sound)

Is there a way to play TF2 without an emulator or at least having to download the whole thing again (windows version for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cant run TF2 on Linux with an Intel GMA 4500m or HD. I'm currently having problems because of how old the integrated graphics are.